# What's needed to sign an update to an existing iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova, itunes

This is kind of a convoluted scenario, so bear with me.

I'm working on a new version of an existing app, though it's essentially rebuilt from the ground up; the first version was built by a third party using some app studio package but was signed and submitted to iTunes with our Apple credentials.

This version is built with Cordova (using the CLI), is basically all there, runs in the emulator, but when I try to compile for a device:

```
 cordova build ios --device
```

the build fails after throwing two errors:

```
 Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching "iPhone Developer" were found.
 CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

Now...I do have my certificate (named "iPhone Developer: My Name (...") in keychain, so I figure it's the "private key" part of that requirement that's hanging me up, but the only guides I can find online for how to add a key are written assuming I'm using XCode, which I'm not using directly here (because I'm building via Cordova CLI).

Any idea what I can do here?